# How to make changes in script files like widget.js , store,js and make them reflecting in the store of Aurora JQuery Store?

Tags: websphere-commerce, wcs, libwcs

I am using Aurora JQuery Store (WCS 8), I want to make changes in the java script files (widget.js, store.js , vendor.js) but when i make make changes directly in those files its not getting reflected. Please explain the flow of making changes in the script files of WCS 8 - Aurora JQuery Store.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the overall picture here: [jQuery Aurora starter store](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.aurora-starterstore.doc/refs/rsmaurorajquerydev.htm)

There is a build/re-build stage involved to combine, minify, etc. JS & CSS (step 3).

Comment: Is this the only way? Because for making a simple script change in development environment, I need to follow these many steps to get the change reflect in the store.

Comment: As far as I know, the source scripts (i.e. where you are thinking of making the changes) are not used/seen directly by the page on the browser, so your script changes won't be in the JS file that is used.
How long is the grunt step taking?

Comment: Please refer https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.aurora-starterstore.doc/tasks/tsmaurorarebuild_jquery.htm

Comment: "Please refer"?

Comment: Is there any option to stop Minification in development environment?

Comment: There will be an option to stop it, but think what will that do. Your issue is not minification, but the "combine" part. I.e. the part that can take multiple files and produce a single one.
Now, even if you disable that combining, what front-end code will know of the original JS files in order to use them?
So, not only you'll have to disable any combining, but also change pages using JS, so they now use the un-combined files. I hope it's obvious what will all this result into.